# JS Get background image then display in lightbox

Tags: javascript

I have a set of **divs** with background images. Im trying to get the image `onclick` then display it in a lightbox. When the lightbox pops, the image i get in undefined. I can get the image *url* to display correctly through **console**. I know `lbImg.src = galImg.src;` is incorrect but i am unsure how to fix it.

HTML

```
<div id="lightbox">
    <span class="closeBTN">&times;</span>

    <img class="lbContent" src="">
 </div>

<div class="imgCon">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.imgCon
{
 height: 500px;
 width: 15%;
 min-width: 200px;
 background-image: url(../images/01.jpg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: auto 500px;
 margin-bottom: 66px;
}
```

JS

```
var lightbox = document.querySelector('#lightbox')
    img = document.querySelector('.imgCon')
    span = document.querySelector('.closeBTN')
    lbImg = document.querySelector('.lbContent')

img.onclick = (function(){
    lightbox.style.display = "block";
    var galImg = window.getComputedStyle(this, 
    null).getPropertyValue("background-Image");
    lbImg.src = galImg.src;
    //console.log(galImg);
})

span.onclick = (function(){
    lightbox.style.display = "none";

});
```

Comment: what is "imgCon"?? Please post complete code

Comment: imgcon is just the images container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the background-image itself in `galImg`, so you need to set it directly (it is a string and does not have a `.src` property).

But, the value of galImg we obtain from getComputedStyle is a string like as: `"url("file:.../Desktop/1.png")"`. We have to remove the `url(` part and also the quotation marks ("...") from it:

```
lbImg.src = galImg.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try `lbImg.setAttribute('src', galImg.src)`.

Comment: This give me the same result.